# What do the X(), Y() and Z() macros do in LLVM?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm

I found this code in Sparc LLVM backend:

```
extern "C" void LLVMInitializeSparcTargetInfo() {
  RegisterTarget<Triple::sparc, /*HasJIT=*/true> X(TheSparcTarget, "sparc",
                                                   "Sparc");
  RegisterTarget<Triple::sparcv9, /*HasJIT=*/true> Y(TheSparcV9Target,
                                                     "sparcv9", "Sparc V9");
  RegisterTarget<Triple::sparcel, /*HasJIT=*/true> Z(TheSparcelTarget,
                                                     "sparcel", "Sparc LE");
}
```

I don't understand what these `X`, `Y`, `Z` macros do and I cannot find any definition or documentation for them.

Comment: They aren't macros, they are the names of the three objects declared in that function. Probably they are declared just for some side-effect of the `RegisterTarget` constructor. You want to look up the documentation of the `RegisterTarget` template class.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: That's an answer not a comment - and one that had already been posted at that!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I posted that as a comment (*before* your answer) because I was on a bus and didn't had time to do an in-depth search on what `RegisterTarget` actually is and does (which I normally would have done before posting it as a proper answer).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Sorry, no, according to the timestamps it was a whole minute and a half later ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: curses! My bus must have achieved relativistic speed, there's no other explanation! =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What makes you think that these are macros?

To me, `X`, `Y` and `Z` look like throwaway names for instantiation of registration objects.

You should instead be looking for the documentation of `RegisterTarget`.